# Disabling an input on Toggle, in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle a div and disable a input box if a checkbox is selected. This code works for toggling the DIV, but does not re-enable the input box. This was working prior to upgrading to jQuery 1.9.

Any ideas?

```
$(".myLink").on("click", function(){
    $(".newDiv").toggle(); // Toggle the div to show/hide
    $(".myInput").val('').prop('disabled', $(this).attr('checked')); // Disable the input box if the checkbox is checked.
});
```

Comment: I found the [DependsOn](https://github.com/dstreet/dependsOn) and [Disabler Widget](http://dougestep.com/dme/jquery-disabler-widget) plugins which you might find useful

Answer (score 7):

`attr` doesn't return a boolean value, you can use `prop` method or `checked` property of the DOM Element object instead.

```
$(".myInput").val('').prop('disabled', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

Or:

```
$(".myInput").val('').prop('disabled', this.checked);
```